# Determine which trace flags are set as a startup parameter vs. enabled globally?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

Probably a quick question.

We are looking to test out a couple trace flags as startup parameters in our environment, and while I know we can use `DBCC TRACESTATUS` to get global-scoped trace flags, it doesn't specify whether this was set at startup or merely set with the -1 flag.  Is parsing the SQL error log the only method available?  Possibly a registry entry somewhere?

Any way this can be tackled programmatically would be useful.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are running **SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 and up** then you can query <kbd>**`sys.dm_server_registry`**</kbd> to find out TRACE FLAGS that are enabled at startup.

```
select * from sys.dm_server_registry
where 
cast(value_data  as varchar(max)) like '%-T%'
```

[image]

Just incase if you or future visitors need the output in one row then, you can use below T-SQL :

```
select distinct @@SERVERNAME as SERVER_NAME
                ,replace(STUFF((
                        select ' ' + cast(value_data as varchar(max))
                        from sys.dm_server_registry
                        where cast(value_data as varchar(max)) like '%-T%'
                        for xml PATH('') -- select it as XML
                    ), 1, 1, ' ')        -- This will remove the first character ";" from the result
        , '&#x00', '')                   -- This will remove the "&#x00" else you will get  -traceFlag&#x00
    as TRACE_FLAGS_ENABLED_AT_STARTUP
from sys.dm_server_registry
where cast(value_data as varchar(max)) like '%-T%'
```

[image]

Comment: Never heard of sys.dm_server_registry.  Nice!  We've got some 2008's out there but it looks like some spelunking the registry will be the way to go.

Comment: For older versions, you have to query the registry hive. SQLArg`n` - where `n` increases in number with each additional startup parameter.